# Tomcat doesn't stop with SNMP options

Tags: linux, tomcat, snmp

We have an monitoring application using SNMP, I have enable SNMP in my tomcat server with following option in `bin/setenv.sh` file.

```
#
# SNMP for Tomcat
#
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.interface=10.101.21.31"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.port=1651"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.acl=false"
```

At tomcat startup no issue at all everything is clean. but when i am stopping tomcat i am getting this error.

```
[tomcat@webserver1 bin]$ ./catalina.sh stop
JAVA_OPTS: %JAVA_OPTS%
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat7.1
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat7.1
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat7.1/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat7.1/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7.1/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Error: Failed to start SNMP adaptor with address: /10.101.21.31:1651 (Address already in use)
```

Anyway i can cleanly stop tomcat rather than kill it?

Comment: You need to avoid setting the SNMP options on the JVM for the shutdown process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `CATALINA_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`. The `catalina.sh` script documents the difference quite well:

```
#   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",
#                   "run" or "debug" command is executed.
#                   Include here and not in JAVA_OPTS all options, that should
#                   only be used by Tomcat itself, not by the stop process,
#                   the version command etc.
#                   Examples are heap size, GC logging, JMX ports etc.
```

The fact that `JAVA_OPTS` is set to `%JAVA_OPTS%` also indicates that you have something wrong (probably a script that's been written by a win32 admin).

Comment: This does not work on SLES 11 SP3 where the tomcat init script uses both CATALINA_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS for stop and start.

Comment: If SLES uses `CATALINA_OPTS` for Tomcat start then they have made a mistake: you should file a bug report.